# Configuration Redis on Magento2 errors

Tags: magento2, cache, redis

I already installed and tested Redis working properly on my server. But when I added Redis required settings cache in my `app/etc/env.php` then my Magento 2 displays blank page. I also tried to clean cache by running this command `php bin/magento cache:clean` and I got errors below

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected
>   ''automatic_cleaning_factor'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting
>   ')' in app/etc/env.php on line 101

Below is my `env.php` config:

```
'cache' =>
  array (
    'frontend' =>
    array (
      'default' =>
      array (
        'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
        'backend_options' =>
        array (
          'server' => '127.0.0.1',
          'port' => '6379',
          'persistent' => '',
          'database' => '0',
          'password' => '',
          'force_standalone' => '0',
          'connect_retries' => '1',
          'read_timeout' => '10',
          'automatic_cleaning_factor' => '0',
          'compress_data' => '1',
          'compress_tags' => '1',
          'compress_threshold' => '20480',
          'compression_lib' => 'gzip',
          'use_lua' => '0',
        ),
      ),
      'page_cache' =>
      array (
        'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
        'backend_options' =>
        array (
          'server' => '127.0.0.1',
          'port' => '6379',
          'persistent' => '',
          'database' => '1',
          'password' => '',
          'force_standalone' => '0',
          'connect_retries' => '1',
          'lifetimelimit' => '57600',
          'compress_data' => '0',
          'compress_tgs'  => '1',
          'compress_threshold' => '20480',
          'compression_lib' => 'gzip'
          'automatic_cleaning_factor' => '0',
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

I don't know reason why? Did I miss configuration setting in Magento or I had to disable memcached in Magento 2.

**EDIT**

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'CredisException' with message
>   'Connection to Redis failed after 2 failures.Last Error : (13)
>   Permission denied' in
>   /var/www/magento2/vendor/colinmollenhour/credis/Client.php:448\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   /var/www/magento2/vendor/colinmollenhour/credis/Client.php(444):
>   Credis_Client->connect()\n#1
>   /var/www/magento2/vendor/colinmollenhour/credis/Client.php(774):
>   Credis_Client->connect()\n#2
>   /var/www/magento2/vendor/colinmollenhour/credis/Client.php(604):
>   Credis_Client->__call('select', Array)\n#3
>   /var/www/magento2/vendor/colinmollenhour/cache-backend-redis/Cm/Cache/Backend/Redis.php(144):
>   Credis_Client->select(1)\n#4
>   /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php(153):
>   Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis->__construct(Array)\n#5
>   /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Cache.php(94):
>   Zend_Cache::_makeBackend('Cm_Cache_Backen...', Array, true, true)\n#6
>   /var/www/magento2/vendor/magento/framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Factory.php(156):
>   Zend_Cache::factory('Ma in
>   /var/www/magento2/vendor/colinmollenhour/credis/Client.php on line 448

Answer (score 6):

You have a typo at the end of your config, you're missing a comma ',' after

```
'compression_lib' => 'gzip'
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. I already added comma ',' but it still raises errors

Comment: the **same** error?

Comment: Well, It raised to me another error message PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'CredisException' with message 'Connection to Redis failed after 2 failures.Last Error : (13) Permission denied' in /var/www/magento2/vendor/colinmollenhour/credis/Client.php:448\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/magento2/vendor/colinmollenhour/credis/Client.php(444): Credis_Client->connect()\n#1 /var/www/magento2/vendor/colinmollenhour/credis/Client.php(774): Credis_Client->connect()\n#2

Comment: Make sure your permissions are set correctly across all files.

Comment: Same problem in CentOS 7, Magento 2.1.8.  Not the comma cause, doesn't find the file permissions problem.

Comment: Are the Redis credentials and configurations correct?

Answer (score 1):

In CentOs 7, you need to enable the SELinux boolean:

> sudo setsebool httpd_can_network_connect on

Comment: This solved it for me

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, turned out the port used by redis (6379 in my case) was being used by other application. So, I changed port in the config and it worked like charm.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. I was getting following error.

```
   "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught CredisException: Connection to Redis redis:6379 failed after 2 failures.Last Error : (0) php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Temporary failure in name resolution in /var/www/html/project/vendor/colinmollenhour/credis/Client.php:475
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/project/vendor/colinmollenhour/credis/Client.php(471): Credis_Client->connect()
#1 /var/www/html/project/vendor/colinmollenhour/credis/Client.php(784): Credis_Client->connect()
```

I had not provided the password and the server name was wrong for me.

```
'cache' => [
    'frontend' => [
        'default' => [
            'id_prefix' => 'a03_',
            'backend' => 'Magento\\Framework\\Cache\\Backend\\Redis',
            'backend_options' => [
                'server' => 'redis', /* I had redis installed locally so I had to enter 127.0.0.1 */
                'database' => '0',
                'port' => '6379',
                'password' => '', /* Here I had not entered password */
                'compress_data' => '1',
                'compression_lib' => '',
                'preload_keys' => [
                    'a03__EAV_ENTITY_TYPES',
                    'a03__GLOBAL_PLUGIN_LIST',
                    'a03__DB_IS_UP_TO_DATE',
                    'a03__SYSTEM_DEFAULT',
                ],
            ]
        ],
```

Answer (score -1):

First, check the Redis host in your env file you can use your **env.php** based on my env file that I use in my [Magento 2 Docker container](https://github.com/clean-docker/Magento2) to avoid future issues:

```
<?php
return array (
  'backend' => 
  array (
    'frontName' => 'admin',
  ),
  'crypt' => 
  array (
    'key' => '5e56dc6d8f24f711bb4f289cca1beda9',
  ),
  'session' => 
  array (
    'save' => 'redis',
    'redis' => 
    array (
      'host' => 'redis-session',
      'port' => '6379',
      'password' => '',
      'timeout' => '2.5',
      'persistent_identifier' => '',
      'database' => '2',
      'compression_threshold' => '2048',
      'compression_library' => 'gzip',
      'log_level' => '1',
      'max_concurrency' => '6',
      'break_after_frontend' => '5',
      'break_after_adminhtml' => '30',
      'first_lifetime' => '600',
      'bot_first_lifetime' => '60',
      'bot_lifetime' => '7200',
      'disable_locking' => '0',
      'min_lifetime' => '60',
      'max_lifetime' => '2592000',
    ),
  ),
  'db' => 
  array (
    'table_prefix' => '',
    'connection' => 
    array (
      'default' => 
      array (
        'host' => 'db',
        'dbname' => 'magento',
        'username' => 'magento',
        'password' => 'magento',
        'active' => '1',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'resource' => 
  array (
    'default_setup' => 
    array (
      'connection' => 'default',
    ),
  ),
  'x-frame-options' => 'SAMEORIGIN',
  'MAGE_MODE' => 'production',
  'cache_types' => 
  array (
    'config' => 1,
    'layout' => 1,
    'block_html' => 1,
    'collections' => 1,
    'reflection' => 1,
    'db_ddl' => 1,
    'eav' => 1,
    'customer_notification' => 1,
    'full_page' => 1,
    'config_integration' => 1,
    'config_integration_api' => 1,
    'translate' => 1,
    'config_webservice' => 1,
    'compiled_config' => 1,
    'amasty_shopby' => 1,
    'target_rule' => 1,
  ),
  'install' => 
  array (
    'date' => 'Thu, 05 Jan 2017 22:49:50 +0000',
  ),
  'cache' => 
  array (
    'frontend' => 
    array (
      'default' => 
      array (
        'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
        'backend_options' => 
        array (
          'server' => 'redis',
          'port' => '6379',
          'persistent' => '',
          'database' => '0',
          'password' => '',
          'force_standalone' => '0',
          'connect_retries' => '1',
          'read_timeout' => '10',
          'automatic_cleaning_factor' => '0',
          'compress_data' => '1',
          'compress_tags' => '1',
          'compress_threshold' => '20480',
          'compression_lib' => 'gzip',
          'use_lua' => '0',
        ),
      ),
      'page_cache' => 
      array (
        'backend' => 'Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis',
        'backend_options' => 
        array (
          'server' => 'redis',
          'port' => '6379',
          'persistent' => '',
          'database' => '1',
          'password' => '',
          'force_standalone' => '0',
          'connect_retries' => '1',
          'lifetimelimit' => '57600',
          'compress_data' => '0',
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```